# How do you display how much space is taken up by all the contents held recursively in one directory using a Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I use Ubuntu 9.04 and I would like to know how to display how much space is taken up by all the contents held recursively in one directory using a Linux terminal?

Should I use `ls -l` along with some other options?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
du -sh <your-dir>
```

Where:

- *s* means summarize this directory only
- *h* means human-readable units (MB, GB etc)

Comment: The -s means "summarize this directory only", and -h means "human-readable units (like MB, GB)".

Comment: If this were code du -sh -> alias disc-usage=du; disc-usage --human-readable --summarize

Comment: This also works just fine under windows, with Cygwin.

Comment: The `-c` option (produce a total line) tends to also be helpful, if you need to specify a few arguments!